# Trying to start two .bat files with a .bat file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to set up a Minecraft Server and actually everything works fine. I'm starting the Server with a launch.bat file.

```batch
"%ProgramFiles%\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe" -Xmx2G -Xms1G -jar Tekkit.jar nogui
pause
```

And I have a second .bat file for backup purposes.

```batch
SET COUNTER=0
:loop
SET /a COUNTER=%COUNTER%+1
XCOPY "Server\*" "c:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Tekkit Server\backups\server_backup_%COUNTER%" /i /s
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 600000 > NUL
goto loop
```

Now, all I'm trying to do is to start the two .bat files simultaneously, using only one .bat file.

I tried it with a third .bat file to start all:

```
start cmd /k CALL "C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Tekkit Server\Server\launch.bat"
start cmd /k CALL "C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Tekkit Server\backup.bat"
pause
```

It will actually start both .bat files, but suddenly, they start acting up and won't find their own files again:

> `C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_20\bin\java.exe" -Xmx2G -Xms1G -jar Tekkit.jar nogui`
>   Error: Unable to access jarfile Tekkit.jar
>
> `C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop>pause`
>   Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
>
> `C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop>SET COUNTER=0`
>   `C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop>SET /a COUNTER=0+1`
>   `C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop>XCOPY "Server\*" "c:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Tekkit 
>    Server\backups\server_backup_1" /i /s`
>   File * not found
>   0 File(s) copied
>
> `C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop>PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 600000  1>NUL`

All three .bat files are in different directories.
Does anybody have a clue what I could do about my problem (besides stop being lazy, trying to reduce 2 clicks down to one ;) )
Thanks a lot
Benny

Comment: Try doing `start /d %cd%` instead.  (This sets it to the current directory)

Comment: set your paths correctly. note that the current directiory for your scripts is your desktop. specify the jar and backup dir absolutely.

Comment: Like this? `start /d %cd% CALL "C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Tekkit Server\Server\launch.bat"
start /d %cd% CALL "C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Tekkit Server\backup.bat"
pause
`

Comment: How do I specify them absolutely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely your path directory.  when you do cmd, cd to the "right" directory first, then run the bat file.  for example:

cmd /k "cd /my/app/path && app.bat"

the && is the separator for multiple commands

Comment: With or without the Call command? I'm sorry, I'm completely lost.

Comment: without the CALL.  start cmd /K "cd \blah\blah\blah && launcher.bat"

Comment: That's the Path for the one batch file I want to integrate. Could you please show me, how the Command should look? `"C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Tekkit Server\Server\launch.bat"`

Comment: cmd /k "cd /d c:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\Tekkit Server\Server && launch.bat"

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Thank you very much! I'd give you an upvote, but my reputation is not high enough yet. But I'll definitey come back to that. Once again, thank you very much!!!

Comment: `&& is the separator for multiple commands` kinda; `&&` only allows the command on its right to execute if the command on its left returns with an error code of `0`.